# Django SQLite in memory

Tags: sqlite, django-1.7

I have a small table with 100-1000 rows, on which selects and appending/deleting rows performs relatively often.

1. Will it be better solution to move this table to separate SQLITE database , which can be stored in RAM (with custom router):

   'ramdb': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       'NAME': ':memory:',
    }

Or my main mysql database will automatically bring better performance?

2. Will the database content be saved between requests?
3. Does :memory: database support 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True?
4. Do I need to perform makemigrations and migrate for it?

Comment: No, in memory databases are... in memory. They have no disk file. Your changes will not be saved. Unless you have a performance problem, stick to what works.

Comment: You mean data will not be saved even between requests? I don't need to save betweeen server restarts.

Comment: I don't know. Django may create a new connection per request, which will correspond to a new in-memory database each time. More likely, it pools connections, which means you would have a bunch of in memory databases and which one you get would be unpredictable. You'd also have to create the schema somehow, since the database would be lost after migrate runs.